# Python console-menu run a command_item inside a selection_menu

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/

I would like to have a menu for ssh'ing to all our boxes. Using a sub menu for Live & UAT.

I just starting out with Python and haven't got to far, using the template provided

````
    from consolemenu import *
    from consolemenu.items import *

    # Create the menu
    menu = ConsoleMenu("Title", "Subtitle")

    # Create some items

    # MenuItem is the base class for all items, it doesn't do anything when selected
    menu_item = MenuItem("Menu Item")

    # A FunctionItem runs a Python function when selected
    function_item = FunctionItem("Call a Python function", input, ["Enter an input"])

    # A CommandItem runs a console command
    command_item = CommandItem("Run a console command",  "touch hello.txt")

    # A SelectionMenu constructs a menu from a list of strings
    selection_menu_uat = SelectionMenu(["item1", "item2", "item3"])
    selection_menu_live = SelectionMenu(["item1", "item2", "item3"])

    # A SubmenuItem lets you add a menu (the selection_menu above, for example)
    # as a submenu of another menu
    submenu_item_live = SubmenuItem("Live", selection_menu_live, menu)
    submenu_item_uat = SubmenuItem("DEV/UAT", selection_menu_uat, menu)

    # Once we're done creating them, we just add the items to the menu
    menu.append_item(menu_item)
    menu.append_item(function_item)
    menu.append_item_test(command_item)
    menu.append_item(submenu_item_live)
    menu.append_item(submenu_item_uat)

    # Finally, we call show to show the menu and allow the user to interact
    menu.show()```

I'd like to have a command_item "ssh" as and "item" within the selection_menu_uat.

Is this even possible. 

Thanks for any help provided.
````